# Question using Hahn-Banach

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Given any two distinct elements $x,y \in X$, prove that there exists a bounded linear map $f: X \to \mathbf{C}$ with $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(x) \ne f(y)$.

My attempt: by a corollary of Hahn-Banach, we have that for each $x \in X$ there is some $\ell_{x} \in X^{*}$ such that $\|\ell_{x}\|=1$ and $\ell_{x}(x)=\|x\|$. So we already have a bounded linear map satisfying the first property but how do I go about showing that $\ell_x(x)\ne \ell_x(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\Bbb C(x-y)$ and let $\varphi\colon M\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ the linear map defined by $\varphi\bigl(\lambda(x-y)\bigr)=\lambda$. Then $\varphi$ is continuous and therefore, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, you can extend it to a $F\in X^*$. Then $F(x-y)=1$. So, take $\frac F{\|F\|}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what is $\mathbf{C}(x-y)$?

Comment: It's $\{\lambda(x-y)\mid\lambda\in\Bbb C\}$. In other words, it's the line spanned by $x-y$.

Comment: oh I see, that is a smart construction, thanks! So is there no way to proceed from my attempt then?

Comment: Yes, You apply that idea not to $x$ but to $x-y$. Then $l_{x-y}(x-y)=\|x-y\|\ne0$ and $\|l_{x-y}\|=1$.

Comment: Ohh right of course, amazing!